# Unable to SSH to AWS on home network?

Tags: ssh, router, port, putty

I am not exactly sure if this is the right place. I have an AWS EC2 instance which I am trying to access using putty on windows 7. I have been doing it using my phone hotspot successfully. But it gives me "Connection Timed out" when I try to connect using my home wifi network.

Any Ideas?

As far as AWS configuration goes I have tried and tested it, and besides I am able to use it using other networks.(So I'm pretty sure it's not AWS configuration that is at fault)

I am using a Dlink600M router.(I dont know if that helps).

Comment: check your firewall and dns settings

Comment: Check your AWS security group, which is effectively a firewall

Answer (score -1):

I have been connecting to AWS all the time using wifi. Make sure you allow SSH traffic to your IP as part of your AWS security group associated with your EC2 instance. Use whatismyip.com to get what IP is your ISP service as established for you. I have seen this change sometimes.
Also, make sure you use the .pem file for authentication.

Comment: Answering offtopic questions only encourages them to be asked.

Comment: @HopelessN00b and where should a person expect to ask such 'offtopic' questions?